# MPMoviePlayerController end of play my screen change to audio streaming controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm using MPMoviePlayerController with streaming with m3u8. I Have big problem that the end of playing my screen change to such as audio controller.

Here are my screenshots.

[image: this screenshot is playing]

After playing change to

[image: end of playing screeshot]

My m3u8 file is..

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1148390
http://ex.com:1935/vod/mp4:1306651297327_3302.mp4/playlist.m3u8?wowzasessionid=65455083
```

and follow http://ex.com...playlist.m3u8?wowzasessionid=65455083

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXTINF:10,
media_1.ts?wowzasessionid=65455083
#EXTINF:10,
media_2.ts?wowzasessionid=65455083
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

I don't know why screen change.

any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You need an #EXT-X-ENDLIST on your master playlist (the one that has a the bandwidth data)
That being said it's not 100% - Have you tried it?