# MPMoviePlayerController changes control style at the end of movie

Tags: objective-c, ipad

Using iOS4(.3) on iPad

MPMoviePlayerController playing video using default control style in a UIView as follows:

```
self.player.view.frame = containerView.bounds;
[containerView addSubview: self.player.view];
```

Controls display as expected with Play/Pause button, time and scrubber etc.

However, upon reaching the end of the media, the media control bar does two things:

1) Changes style - this is the same style I get when I play an MP3

2) Changes location in the view - it's no more docked at the bottom of the UIView anymore but rather in the middle (vertically that is).

Is there a way to stop this behaviour and keep the control bar as it was at the end of the movie?

Found this:
[MPMoviePlayerController end of play my screen change to audio streaming controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194934/mpmovieplayercontroller-end-of-play-my-screen-change-to-audio-streaming-controlle)

Precisely the behaviour I'm getting but on the iPad.

I also tried using Apple's own test link: http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/prog_index.m3u8

Same behaviour. By monitoring **MPMovieMediaTypesAvailableNotification**, I found out that at the end of the stream, the **movieMediaTypes** property changes to Audio (only).

Anyway to force the player to stay on Video source?

Thanks

Comment: same behaviour using Apple test link for HLS: http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/prog_index.m3u8

Answer (score 0):

are you handling the MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification as explained in the [Using Video](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingVideo/UsingVideo.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH3-SW12) documentation ?

When playback is finished, the movie controller sends a notification received by the application controller object, which releases the movie controller now that it is no longer needed.

Comment: I am and I do receive a didFinish.... notification. If I stop the player and/or release it and/or remove it from the superview (tried all combos), I sometimes get a flicker (which is the change of player control style from video to audio) before it disappears.

Comment: While the flicker is simply annoying, I'd quite like a smooth transition. Only things I can think of are: 1) use a custom player bar - that would increase the workload 2) monitor the playback duration and as soon as it hits the total duration, stop the player or simply rewind to position 0 (or frame 1) - Not near my mac, so can try later

Comment: does the movieMediaTypes property changes to Audio (only) as well for the video on Apple's own test link  ? if that is the case you will best file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com and/or open a case with the Apple Developer Connection to get a fix

Comment: Hi Werner, thanks for your suggestions. I eventually worked around it by handling the notification when the movieMediaTypes changes and if I was playing video and the new media types is audio, then I simply hide the media control (as I know it's a split second from the end). I reinstate the media control when the user plays another media or replays the same media. This is a temp fix, I will provide my own media control UI on the next revision as it'll come handy for all apps needing media playback.